# Can I apply a style to a XAML element based on what parent element it has?

Tags: xaml, styles, conditional-statements, controltemplate

What is the correct way to apply styles on elements with a condition on their parent element's type, i. e. only if they are children of certain other elements?

In my case, I want to apply some exact button width and height, but only if those buttons are direct children of a stackpanel. Additionally, a second style should be applied to images within those buttons (glyphs).

- How do I define a button style that only affects buttons on a stackpanel, but not those buttons placed directly on a grid?
- Is it possible to add additional conditions such as *only stackpanels with `orientation="horizontal"`*?
- Can I define "tree conditions" like *only images on buttons on [horizontal] stackpanels*?

As 90% of all buttons in my application are those on the stackpanels, so far I've applied the style to all buttons and images and overrode it where necessary. But this isn't the best solution, is it?

Preferably, the solution would deal with all the conditions in the style definition, so I won't have to explicitly assign that style to every single one of my stackpanels.

Answer (score -1):

```
<StackPanel>
   <StackPanel.Resources>
      <Style x:Key="Rectangle1" TargetType="Rectangle">
        <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Black" />
        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="White" />                                            
      </Style>                                      
   </StackPanel.Resources>
   <UniformGrid Columns="10">
      <UniformGrid.Resources>
         <Style TargetType="Rectangle" BasedOn="{StaticResource Rectangle1}">
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Red" />                                          
     </Style>                                       
      </UniformGrid.Resources>

    </UniformGrid>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could edit your post to include some brief explanation.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't see how this is related to my question. I am aware I can override setters from base-styles. But my question was asking about whether I can add conditions to my one and only style definition in a form of requiring certain parent element types to let the whole style become applied at all, like I have my style definition in one place, and it is applied on children of certain elements, but not on the children of all other elements.